# NgRx state add/update as array and keep in sync

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx

How do you update state with ngrx if you need to add more than one object?

For instance, in the example below, one user can be associated with more than one task.

Currently, when all tasks are returned, the store is updated twice, and on each update the last task is replaced by a new one. This is expected behaviour, but how would you initialise an array and capture updates to state as an array of objects and **ensure that it is kept in sync**?

**task.reducer.ts**

```
import * as TaskActions from './task.actions';
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ITask } from '../../models/task';

export interface State {
  task: ITask | null;
  error: any;
}

const initialState: ITask = {
  basketTotal: 0,
  carePlanPrice: 0,
  category: null,
  completionDate: null
};

export const taskReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(TaskActions.getData, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.dataReceived, (state, payload) => ({ ...state, payload })),
  on(TaskActions.dataNotReceived, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.signOut, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.signOutSuccess, state => ({ ...state, ...initialState })),
);

export function reducer(state: ITask | undefined, action: Action) {
  return taskReducer(state, action);
}
```

**task.effect.ts**

```
  @Effect()
  getData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(TaskActions.getData),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.afs.collection<ITask>('tasks', ref =>
        ref.where('createdBy', '==', localStorage.getItem('uid'))).stateChanges().pipe(
      );
    }),
    mergeMap(actions => actions),
    map(action => {
      if (action.payload) {
        return TaskActions.dataReceived({ payload: TaskService.parseData(action.payload.doc.data()) });
      } else {
        return TaskActions.dataNotReceived();
      }
    })
  );
```

**task.actions.ts**

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ITask } from '../../models/task';

export const getData = createAction('[Task] Get Data');
export const dataReceived = createAction('[Task] Data Received', props<{ payload: Partial<ITask> }>());
export const dataNotReceived = createAction('[Task] Data Not Received');
export const signOut = createAction('[Task] Sign Out');
export const signOutSuccess = createAction('[Task] Sign Out Success');
```

Update:

I tried

```
on(TaskActions.dataReceived, (state, payload) => 
  ({ 
      ...state, 
      tasks: [...state.tasks,  payload.payload ] 
  })),
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I was expecting an array with both items in place:

```
task: [
  { ... }, { ... }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread syntax can also be used for arrays to create a clone.

```
on(TaskActions.dataReceived, (state, payload) => 
  ({ 
      ...state, 
      tasks: payload.condition ? [...state.tasks,  payload.newTask ] : []
  })),
```

See the [Spread syntax docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. This doesn't seem to work

Comment: Could you be more explicit on what you're trying to do please because  `[...original, item]`, appends the a new array based on the original one

Comment: I'd like to sync the store based on the data returned from Firestore, so the user either ends up with an empty array or +n array items once the data is retrieved.

Comment: See the updated answer, you'll have to put a condition to assign the new tasks

Comment: Thanks. What is payload.newTask?

Comment: It's the `+n array items` to add